# iOS UITableView random crash

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios, uitableview

I have a problem I can't locate clearly, maybe you can help me...

I have an iPad project, based on UINavigationController, most (but not all) of controllers inside are instances of UITableViewController, and everything works well...

Everything excepting that my application crashes randomly, sometimes after 10 minutes of use, sometimes after only 10 seconds...
It never crashes on the same view, never at the same time, making that difficult to reproduce.

In addition, it only seams to happen on device, I've never got this crash in the simulator.

The debugger doesn't help me very much, here is what it says:
*-[UITableView autorelease]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x8e9800*

And here is the call stack:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSCHx.png

Any idea ?
Thanks (and sorry for my english)

Comment: Please post text, not images.  More people will actually see the problem and not just skip over it.

Comment: I didn't post text because this isn't a text I can copy/paste, re-typing all this text...
This call stack didn't appear in the debugger, it is only visible in this menu

Comment: Go to the Console, it's copy/pasteable there.  Also helps search engines find this question in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overreleasing a UITableView somewhere in your code. Are you calling `release` or `autorelease` on the UITableView inside one of your UITableViewControllers? You should only release objects that you 'own'. You get to own an object by using methods beginning with `alloc`, `new`, `copy`, or `retain`.

Please read the cocoa memory management guidelines for more info.

Useful links:

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MemoryManagement

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?RulesOfThumb

Comment: I never call release or autorelease on an IBOutlet

Answer (score 0):

At some point you are either releasing a UITableView instance that you do not own or you are failing to `retain` one at some point where you keep a reference to it (e.g. you store it in an ivar or a property declared assign rather than retain).

Comment: I don't use property to attach IBOutlet, only variables so I never release or autorelease them.
And the crash is totally random, never happen on the same view
I believe this can be caused by an incorrect parameter in one of my XIB but wich parameter ?
Can this be caused by the fact I don't retain/release my IBOutlets ?

Answer (score 0):

I have written about how to debug things like this on my blog:

http://loufranco.com/blog/files/Understanding-EXC_BAD_ACCESS.html

Basically, try these three things first:

1. Do a Build an Analyze and fix everything you see
2. Turn on Zombies, run your code -- it will tell you if you talk to dealloced objects
3. If that fails, try Debug Malloc, but that's way harder.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize, after re-reading all my source code, I found ONE ViewController (I have around 20 ViewController), where I released an Outlet, in ViewDidUnload.

The reason that it crashed randomly is that I didn't understood well the mechanism of ViewDidUnload, it is called to release views (but not objects of controllers) when memory is low and view is not visible (ex: First ViewController of a NavigationController), and the views are re-loaded when the ViewController become visible again...

In simulator, memory is rarely an issue so ViewDidUnload is almost never called...

Problem fixed, thank you everyone for your help

Answer (score 0):

To help with making sense of the trace, see [iOS Debugging Magic (Technical Note TN2239)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2239/_index.html) and [Understanding and Analyzing iPhone OS Application Crash Reports (Technical Note TN2151)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html).

Jeff